# Why is this Type I compensator phase not 270 degrees?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator, compensation

This is a Type I compensator with a pole at origin. The transfer function between \$V_{in}\$ and \$V_{out}\$ is as follows:

$$ \frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}= -\frac{R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}} \frac{1}{s (R_{1}|| R_{2})C_{1}} $$

According to this formula, this compensator should always cause a phase delay of \$270^{\circ} \$ at ALL frequencies with \$180^{\circ}\$ from the inverting amplifier and \$90^{\circ}\$ from the origin pole.

However, in the simulation I have set up below, the phase delay at 0.1 Hz is only about \$180^\circ\$.

What is the reason here?

The OpAmp is one-pole model with DC gain of 1000 V/V and pole at 1MHz. 
This is the model: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Ldi.jpg

And this is simulation file using Multisim: https://ufile.io/p20r4
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your ac source should have the same DC level as Vbias, as the opamp has no way to pull the inputs back together

Comment: @sstobbe: yes, it has offset of 5V.

Answer (score 1):

The op-amp you have used has a DC open-loop gain of only about 54 dB and I expect the capacitor C1 doesn't start to "eat into" the open loop gain until some frequency that is higher than about 10 Hz.

An integrator is only as good as the open-loop gain (at low frequencies).

---

I will also point out that in the circuit you show (with R2 connected to ground) R2 has no effect on the frequency response of the circuit and that your equation for the gain and integrator time constant does not involve R2. The -input of the op-amp is a virtual earth for AC signals.

Comment: I tried to change the gain to 200dB and the phase delay at frequency from 0.1 to 1kHz almost 180 degrees. It doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Try again without C1 - if the open loop gain is still 54 dB ish then your changes were ineffective.

Comment: Without C1, the phase also 180 degree until 100kHz

Comment: And the open loop gain is?.....

Comment: Also, why do you think the gain is dependent on R2? The inverting input is a virtual earth and so R2 is irrelevant unless of course you have it connected somewhere else that you have not indicated in your question.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake including R2. The open loop gain is 54dB. But why 54dB not 60? 1000V/V --> 60dB?

Comment: I can only tell you what your graphs tell me.

Comment: When I change the gain to 10^10 V/V, I run open loop and the magnitude is minus 21dB. I think maybe the problem is somewhere here.

Comment: Gain is dependent on input impedance, feedback ratio, Aol and GBW constant

Comment: This simulation is set up to have a crossover frequency at 3kHz and gain at crossover frequency is 6dB. C1 is chosen to satisfy this criterion. I simulated and checked this spec is good. However, the phase is strange to me.

Comment: @anhnha I don't know what you expect me to say. Clearly and unambiguously you have a model that is giving strange results. Fix that model. I cannot know what that model is or what it's doing other than what the graphs tell me.

Comment: @Andyaka: I see the phase converges to 270 degrees at high frequencies now. But how do you know this `the capacitor C1 doesn't start to "eat into" the open loop gain until some frequency that is higher than about 10 Hz`?

Comment: @anhnha  As I stated above in my answer it is due to impedance ratio  This is an integrator breakpoint at -45deg relative to DC

Comment: @anhnha either C1 eats into the open loop gain or something internal to the amplifier model (undisclosed by you) is eating into the open-loop gain and reducing it from about 10 Hz and higher.

Comment: Yes, maybe I have to sit down and examine the model file now. It is from a book so not maybe it take a while to understand the model.

Comment: Phase response is normal but GBW is unknow for model

Answer (score 1):

DC gain ~54 dB is inverting
 +180 = -180 deg   so C1 has no affect at DC or 0.1Hz

Pole is at 10 Hz where you expect -45 deg shift from this we can tell you C1.

At Pole |Zc|= Rin and gain drops 3dB from 54 to 51dB then -6dB per octave (x2f)

Then 2 decades higher in f phase reaches 180-90 deg.= 90 deg = -270 deg

Comment: Why there is a pole at 10Hz?

Comment: If the OpAmp is ideal with infinite gain and bandwidth, then should the phase delay always be 270 degrees?

Comment: Yes 2 decades after breakpoint    You said DC gain is 1000 but did not say GBW or value of C1 !! If it is 100kHz GBW then the Pole is at 10Hz

Comment: The value of C1 is calculated in the model file so that the gain at 3kHz is 6dB. R1 = R2 = 10k.

Comment: So closed loop GBW =6000? And Open loop must be much more. Which OpAmp?

Comment: I have to study the model now. It is a bit complex so it will take a while.  The closed-loop gain is 54dB at DC and 0dB crossover frequency is about 6kHz.

Comment: This is OpAmp model file. I know it is difficult to understand but just in case anyone know it. 
https://imgur.com/9DKSk70

Comment: With 2 decades lead to phase shift 90 degrees,  are you considering the pole created by the OpAmp not origin pole? If so where is the origin pole effect?

Comment: Depends on GBW/Aol = Pole

Comment: So should  we have 3 things cause phase delay? 1. Inverting amplifier (180 degrees). 2. Origin pole generated by the integrator. 3. Pole of OpAmp?

Comment: It depends on Op Amp and circuit parameters  The closed loop gain must be << open loop gain for external RC to be simple impedance ratio otherwise internal compensation interferes from lack of feedback gain.  It is best if you disclose more info on specs